# How to restrict games installation

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I am a iPhone person and my wife is andriod. Our son has been madly installing games despite me hiding the play store icon in a folder he manage to find it. I went into playstore setting but the restriction is so confusing, basically what I want is our son not installing ANY games unless we want by parental code.

How Can I do that?

Comment: Maybe just disable Play Store until you want to install some app?

Comment: @iBug how do I do that?

Comment: Settings -> Apps -> Scroll down and find Play Store -> Disable

Comment: Why don't you setup a restricted account such as Guest account for your son? Remove Play Store(using ADB) for that account permanently. Having a  restricted account, your son won't be able to sideload either.

Comment: @Firelord I have no idea what is ADB